# Opera glasses and interference of light

Tags: optics, visible-light, interference

One sunny day my kids asked me about the light circle (see photo below) they noticed on a small wooden bench in a dark room with no windows (there are just doors to other rooms and kids usually sit on the bench when we come in). The colours was like from rainbow.

We tried to trace the path of the light - it brings us to another room (about 4 meters long) with a big window full of sun lights. Finally our grandpa recognized a small opera glasses on the windowsill. Indeed, opera glasses help audiences get closer to the action in theatre. But I am not sure which way the sun lights were transformed to the rainbow via the optical device? I wonder how the opera glasses produced the rainbow at a few meter distance?

Just to add more details. I touched the opera glasses to make sure I am on the right path. Unfortunately, for some reasons the rainbow became less coloured. In a few minutes later I failed to get the clear picture at all. I guess it's all about interference of light, but how it works?
Any explanations are very welcomed.
[image: Lights from a distant opera glasses]
[image: Lights from a distant opera glasses in dark room]

Comment: chromatic aberration https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_aberration

Comment: @hyportnex Thank you, but I can't see at wiki that the chromatic aberration produces the rainbow circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First some general remarks about seperation of light into the constituent colors

When light is separated into the constituent colors by a prism, the optics of that seperation is referred to as 'dispersion'

(Entering the query 'prism dispersion' in a search engine will produce many examples.)

Instrumental in that chromatic dispersion is that the faces of a prism are not parallel.

(The faces of a window pane are parallel to each other, and as a consequence for light that passes through the window pane any cromatic effect cancels out.)

The faces of the lens of the opera glasses are curved of course, but other than that: the faces of the lens are parallel only in the center, everywhere else the (local tangent surfaces) are at an angle with respect to each other.

While in the case of a prism the chromatic dispersion is what you want, in the case of any form of magnifying device you would prefer to not have any chromatic dispersion.

High end optical devices have multiple lenses, combined in such a way that chromatic effects are mitigated.

Opera glasses are a very simple design that leaves no room to mitigate chromatic effects.

When chromatic effect occurs in a context where you don't want it, the cromatic effect is referred to as 'chromatic aberration'.

It's still an instance of 'dispersion', but the shift to the word 'aberration' expresses that now it's an inconvenience.

The color bands we see in the picture are a spectrum.
The light was separated into the constituent colors because it so happened that a beam of light entered the opera glasses at a angle such that the non-parallel faces of the lens made that section of the lens act as a prism.

Comment: Thank you. Can you add a picture of the lens to see the 'prism'. What are the conditions to get the prism, which size?